# Equivalent resistance of circuit

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, resistance, simulation, multisim

I have a simple resistor circuit that i would like to know the equivalent resistance of(as seen from the multimeter terminals):
[image]

The image is from Multisim and the resistance is here measured using simulation. I am not sure about the calculation by hand, but my bet is(from right side of the circuit):

(R10+R9+R8)+(R5||R7)+((R6+R2+R1)||(R4+R3))

Which equals:

[image]

This is close to the simulated result, but I am not sure if my equivalent calculation is correct.Do I need to apply a Star/Delta ?                         Can anyone state a correct method of solving this          or come up with the correct answer  with working ?

Comment: Is this some kind of assignments or homework? I say this because your calculations are wrong, since this circuit cannot be reduced to a simple resistor by using only series and parallel transformations (you end up having a delta/star connection in that).

Answer (score 1):

That circuit can be simplified only to a point by using only series/parallel transformations. By using those you end up with this circuit:

[image]

where \$R12 = R1 + R2 \$, \$R34 = R3 + R4\$ and \$Rs = R8 + R9 + R10\$.

As you can see no further reduction can be done with series or parallel transformations.

At this point you have two possibilities:

1. Apply a voltage source to the terminals, calculate (using mesh analysis, for example) the current drawn by the circuit and calculate the equivalent resistance as V/I.
2. Simplify the circuit further applying the so called [star/delta transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform).

With the second approach you need in particular [these formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform#Equations_for_the_transformation_from_.CE.94_to_Y) to transform, for example, the delta connection of R5, R6 and R7 into a star connection. Once you do this, the circuit can be further simplified using usual series/parallel transformations.